# docker-compose with build in rancher

Tags: docker, docker-compose, catalog, rancher

I create rancher catalog, load a docker-compose file of container that has build, like this

```
m1:
  build: ./machine1/
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
```

and when I start the app in rancher I get the error

> build not supported.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide us with more information. Maybe this article (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help you out as well :)

Comment: have tried:) what else information is needed?